# What kind of changes result in a conflict?

Tags: git, git-merge

I was wondering whether there is a way to predict and thus avoid conflicts upon merging?

So my question is: what kind of changes actually result in conflicts? It's hard to deduce this from experimentation.

If I make code changes what kind of changes are harmless and what kind of changes will lead to merge problems and will require user attention?

For example:

- adding new lines
- replacing lines
- removing lines
- changing a line by adding/removing text (at the beginning, at the end or in the middle)

Are there any rules?

Comment: If Git's algorithm can't figure out how to rationalize two versions of the same story, it will conflict out instead of auto merging.  You shouldn't be worrying about this, just focus on writing good code.  I have seen conflicts from all the scenarios you describe.

Answer (score 1):

When in two branches there have been changes in the same files and in the same lines there will be conflicts, otherwise there should be no conflicts.

Comment: I don't think this is always true.  So you are saying if I add a single comment to a `.java` file e.g. `// comment` there will always be a conflict?

Comment: Only if someone else has editted that line or adjacent lines. In other words, conflicts occur when there are overlapping changes so the version control system don't know how to apply those changes.

Comment: I've seen conflicts in comments. Just add one space before the comment in one brahnc and add a word in that comment in another branch and merge them.

Comment: Oh, I had hoped that merging is smarter than just comparing the entire line with the same line in the same file in another merge but I guess for this it would have to understand the file type that is being merged.

Comment: Well, maybe it can be configured somehow but, in my experience, it always needs help even if some imports (java files) have been added/removed in different branches in the same lines and it would be really easy to say add both automatically and then if some import is not used I'll delete it later on. But I've always had to resolve the conflict by adding all the imports myself.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, changes that affect the same lines are what cause conflicts. If you add remove a line, and someone else changes it, or you change the indentation and they change the line, you will have a conflict.

That is not to say that changes that don't cause conflicts can't mess things up for each other, as one change 10 lines above yours, that doesn't conflict with yours in source control, can easily remove or rename a variable your change is using. This is why automated build systems exist :)

Comment: So a general rule of thumb would be that if two people mess with the same file it's likely that there will be a conflict when we try to merge them. This is good to know because then we can coordinate our work better and avoid resolving those conflicts. Sure, there might by other errors but it's easier to resolve debugger/compiler issues in the IDE then repository issues.

Comment: Sure, that works as a general rule, though one large projects, when you've built up lots of utility functions and similar, you'll still get issues when not modifying the same file.

For instance, your project may have a utility class to load config settings, user "Bob" changes that functionality and updates the code everywhere, but "Alice" started using the config in a new file she wrote. The entirely new file now breaks the build because Alice didn't call the function the way Bob's changes require.